# wordpress get_terms and WP_Query not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

i've created a colophon for my website in which i post all the logos of the different sponsors i have. I add all the sponsors via custom post type. i also added a specific custom taxonomy to distinguish between the different typologies of sponsorships.

I use this code in the footer.php to display them:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms('sponsor_tipology'); 
$count = count( $terms );
if ( $count > 0 ) {
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
      <div class="col-xs-12 <?php echo $term->slug ;?>">      
         <h3><?php  echo $term->name;?></h3> 
         <?php $arg = array (
               'post_type' => 'colophone', 
               'post_per_page' => -1,
               'sponsor_edition' => 'current',
               'sponsor_tipology' => $term->slug,
               );

         $pesca_post = new WP_Query ($arg);
         $quanti_post = $pesca_post->post_count;

         if(have_posts()){ 
            while ($pesca_post->have_posts()) : $pesca_post->the_post();
               $featured = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'large');

               if ($quanti_post == 5){
                  $classe_bootstrap = 15;
               }elseif ($quanti_post > 5){
                  $classe_bootstrap = "2 text-center";
               }elseif($quanti_post < 5){
                  $classe_bootstrap = 12/$quanti_post;
               }

              echo '<div class="col-md-' . $classe_bootstrap . '">'; 
                 if (isset($featured)){
                    $img = $featured;
                 }else{
                    $img = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/placeholder.png';
                 } ?>
               <a href="<?php echo esc_attr(get_permalink($msd_settings['partner_page'])); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?>" >
                  <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url($img); ?>); height:100px;background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;"></div>
               </a>
              <?php   echo '</div>';
      endwhile;
     }?>
    </div>
<?php }
}?>
```

my problem is that this code is completely working just on some pages, on other it shows the contents avoiding the ones belonging to the first term, no matter which it will be.

I have noticed that it works in pagaes where i use other queries.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `wp_reset_query()` or `wp_reset_postdata ()` right before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed it in this way and now it's working!

```
$terms = get_terms('sponsor_tipology');
    $count = count( $terms );  
       if ( $count > 0 ) { 
          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {   //per ogni termine presente 
             $nome = $term->slug;?>
             <div class="col-xs-12 <?php echo $term->slug ;?>">      
                <h3><?php  echo $term->name;?></h3> 
                <?php $arg = array (
                   'post_type' => 'colophone', 
                   'post_per_page' => -1,
                   'sponsor_edition' => 'current',
                   'sponsor_tipology' => $nome,
                   );

                   $elementi = get_posts($arg);
                   $quanti_post = count( $elementi );

                   if ($quanti_post == 5){
                       $classe_bootstrap = 15;
                   }
                   elseif ($quanti_post > 5){
                       $classe_bootstrap = "2 text-center";
                   }
                   elseif($quanti_post < 5){
                       $classe_bootstrap = 12/$quanti_post;
                   }

                   foreach($elementi as $elemento){
                       $featured = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($elemento->ID,'large'); 
                       if (isset($featured)){
                          $img = $featured;
                       }
                       else{
                          $img = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/placeholder.png';
                       } ?>
                       <div class="col-md-<?php echo $classe_bootstrap; ?>"> 
                          <a href="<?php echo esc_attr(get_permalink($msd_settings['partner_page'])); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($elemento->ID);?>" >
                             <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url($img); ?>); height:100px;background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;"></div>
                          </a>
                       </div>
          <?php  }?>
         </div>
   <?php    }
}?>
```